# mailgun - multiple tagging using "o:tag"

Tags: mailgun

I'm trying to multi-tag emails sent from my node (meteor) app. The mailgun docs give the following `curl` snippet:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
[...]
    -F o:tag='September newsletter' \
    -F o:tag='newsletters'
```

So how do you add these multiple tags in a normal JS object?? You can't have duplicate keys in the object, so I tried an array:

```
const params = {to, from, subject, html, "o:tag": ["reminders, "reminder wk1"]}
HTTP.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/myDomain/messages", {params, auth});
```

But the array seems to be `join`ed so the result is only one tag comes up as a single string "reminders, reminder wk1".

So any ideas on adding multiple tags like this? Or do I have to take another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but as i was asking myself the same one here is the answer :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js is now deprecated.
It's recommended to use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun.js

Its not specified in the documentation but you can pass multiple tags :

```
const params = {to, from, subject, html, "o:tag": ['tag1', 'tag2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Response from Mailgun tech support: just use the Mailgun NPM package, which supports multiple tags.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js

(Bizarrely, Mailgun don't monitor questions with the Mailgun tag, hence answering my own question)